# Firefox Addon Publishing API

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, firefox-addon-webextensions

Does Firefox provide access to do the following programmatically?

- Upload Firefox addon package/files
- Update/modify addon package
- Get analytics on extension (installs, uninstalls, etc.)
- Delete/remove addon package

Comment: Have a look at web-ext: https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that at the time of this post, Firefox does not have an API to post addons to their marketplace per their documentation here:  https://extensionworkshop.com/documentation/develop/getting-started-with-web-ext/